# How to create SEO urls in Shopware 6

Tags: seo, shopware, shopware6

I have a shop running on Shopware 6. The data is being migrated into that shop from Magento 1.8. In magento shop one can assign multiple url's to a product. So that a `productA` can be accessed via `shop.domain/productA`, `shop.domain/categoryA/productA`, `shop.domain/categoryA/bategoryB/productA`.

In shopware after the product got imported it only has one link to it - `shop.domain/product-a` (shopware parses the names into url keys differently than magento in case of some more crazy product names that I have).

I need help in having the product have the same links it had in magento - `shop.domain/productA`, `shop.domain/categoryA/productA`, `shop.domain/categoryA/bategoryB/productA`. How can I do that?

If this is not possible then how at least can I assign to the product a custom `url-key` so that it it the same as in magento?

I have found that the product entity in Shopware has a relation to `seo_url` entity and I have been trying to push different combinations to that endpoint via API, for example:

```
'foreignKey' => $shopwareProducts[0]->id,
'salesChannelId' => $germanySalesChannelId,
'routeName' => 'frontend.navigation.page',
'pathInfo' => 'productA',
'seoPathInfo' => 'seoPathInfoTest'.$shopwareProducts[0]->id
```

and it seems to go in without errors, but I have no idea how to make it work on the storefront side (meaning th elink gives me 404). There is a Settings->SEO page where URL seems to be configured but I do not know exactly how to built the snippet to work (tried variations of `{% for part in product.seoUrls %}{{ part.seoPathInfo|lower }}/{% endfor %}`).

The other thing I tried to use is product's Canonical URL settings and enter some paths in SEO path field but it always gets me this error:

```
errors  [ {…} ]
0   Object { status: "404", code: "FRAMEWORK__SEO_URL_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND", title: "Not Found", … }
status  "404"
code    "FRAMEWORK__SEO_URL_ROUTE_NOT_FOUND"
title   "Not Found"
detail  "seo url route\"\" not found."
meta    Object { parameters: {…} }
parameters  Object { routeName: "" }
routeName   ""
```

I am quite new to shopware and all this is very confusing to me :/ Can anyone help please? Shopware documentation is completely unhelpful in this regard. Oh and I need to use the API because I have about 1600 products to import, so cannot do it by hand. I can easily extract all url keys from magento and if I will knoe how to push them into shopware (`seo_url`?) then I will be saved.

Same for categories - is there a way to have them use a different url key?

Also is it possible to assign many url's to a product, or can there be only one?

I do not have the cache enabled yet.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do after all that is to go and refresh your indexes. After that clear the cache.

Settings -> System -> Caches & Indexes

After that the seo urls will be generated. You will have to wait a bit though

Comment: trouble is I do not know if I push data to seo_url in a correct way, or if I am setting up SEO settings in a correct way. So once I set it up and refresh indexes I need to wait... until what? I have no idea if its working :/ Also I do not have cache enabled.

Comment: Ermin means that the generation you actively start takes a while and you might see a while some loading screen. The SEO URLs are generated dependend on the configurable provided pattern.